# does GNU bc offers a standard math library?

Tags: math, gnu, bc

I'm asking if I need to import some kind of library to perform something like that

```
echo "cos(1)" | bc
```

and use BLAS and trigonometric functions in general.

Comment: `man bc` might help with a lot of queries.

Comment: @devnull if focuses more on operators, I was expecting a wider support from the standard math library honestly .

Comment: [GNU octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) might help.

Comment: @devnull I already have the latest version of Octave customized and compiled from source, I was searching for something more friendly and simple to use for when I just need to check something on the fly.

Comment: @devnull Python is kind of another approach, `bc` uses arbitrary precision, Python is like standard C or C++ with IEEE754 representation. but thanks, it's 1 idea that I didn't think of.

Comment: OCaml supports [arbitrary precision arithmetic](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libnum.html).

Comment: @devnull I guess that after discovering that awk doesn't support arbitrary precision I'm about to get serious about functional programming .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the math library with `bc -l`; the cosine function is named `c` in this library:

```
echo "c(1)" | bc -l
```

This library only supports sine, cosine, artangent, the natural logarithm, the exponential function, and (strangely enough) the n-th order Bessel function.

Comment: They are documented in the man page, but for quick reference, they are `s`, `c`, `a`, `l`, `e`, and `j`, respectively.

Comment: I assume that there is no repository or external library that provides the missing pieces ?

Comment: None that I am aware of. I've never quite understood the purpose of `bc`: it's cumbersome, and frankly seems to overlap quite a bit with `awk`.

Comment: I assume that awk doesn't offer arbitrary precision

Comment: Good point (can you tell I've not done a lot of numerical programming?)

Comment: @chepner `bc` was/is an improvement on `dc`, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

This site may offer an extended library (with code available). Quite interesting.

http://phodd.net/gnu-bc/

If someone knows similar libraries please share them.